# Fast MOSFET switch for leading edge about 5ns

Tags: mosfet, switches

I want to calibrate the P6015A Tektronix probe and need a source of about 40-60V pulses (so the probe, which is 1/1000 won't drown it in noise) with the leading edge about 5ns. I have a square generator with insufficient leading edge, so I decided to add something fast after it.

I made switch below, but all I get is a leading edge of 76ns.

Would you please suggest any changes or a different approach?

[image: schematics]

Comment: It would help if you would explain your design assumptions and process here. I assume that you are expecting the 100R/100pF combination to have a 5CR time of 5ns? However this assumes that the input to that circuit is already a perfect edge, which it is not. I would start by calculating the volts-per-second needed to achieve the edge you want, and then how much current that requires into the load capacitance. Then I would start by making sure that the output stage can achieve that. I would think that PCB layout for low capacitance will matter here. It is not easy to make such a circuit.

Comment: Your output stage also looks wrong. If you want a fast leading edge, you need the FET to pull up, not down. Here the fast switch off of the FET doiesn't help as it is not actively driving the load, just removing a short circuit across it. 200R in series with 100pF and all the stray capacitances in your circuit will not even get close to 5ns, and 76ns does not surprise me at all.

Comment: Please use ground symbols instead of wires everywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [IRF620 MOSFET](https://www.vishay.com/docs/91027/irf620.pdf) has an output capacitance of 100 pF. That capacitance is from drain to source internally and, it is that capacitance (along with resistor R1, 100 Ω) that defines the maximum risetime of the output.

At best it's going to be C*R = 10 ns and probably more like 20 ns (if you take the 10% to 90% definition of what risetime is). Then, you need to consider how hard you are driving the gate. Not very hard is the problem; R2 and R5 set the gate drive impedance (267 Ω) and, that has to charge the gate capacitance up (260 pF). That's very nearly 70 ns in its own right.

So, you are feeding a slow risetime into more filtering and that will just add to the woes of the circuit.

May I recommend that you use a source follower GaN MOSFET driven by a fast driver. I've used [EPC GaN parts](https://epc-co.com/epc/) driven by a TI driver chip to achieve around 1 ns rise time at 80 volts. Obviously this is slightly overkill for what you want but, you need to **aim high** with this sort of design.

- [EPC2037 GaN MOSFET](https://epc-co.com/epc/Portals/0/epc/documents/datasheets/EPC2037_datasheet.pdf)
- [LMG1020 gate driver](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lmg1020.pdf?ts=1707231476622&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FLMG1020%253Fqgpn%253Dlmg1020)

I floated both the GaN MOSFET and TI driver chip to form a source follower. I used a Recom isolated dc-dc converter to do this. Sorry, can't give much more on details as it has IP.

Comment: Thank you Andy, that sounds like the path to follow :).

Comment: Ouch, 0.80 mm × 1.20 mm, Andy i can't solder that. Are there any physically largetr parts you would recommend please?

Comment: @Jan unfortunately not. Large size usually means slower speed and I needed 1 ns. What I do in cases like this is that I have a via underneath hard-to-reach pads and solder from below. However, it might be sensible to ask a new question on this site about what folk would recommend for hand soldering parts like this.

Comment: @Jan If we are done here, please take note of this: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.

Comment: I can get UCC27524 or 1EDN7550BXTSA1 driver chips, which are both smd and so they are solderable. What smd MOSFET would you recommend to go with these?

Comment: @Jan I'm not in a position to recommend anything other than what I've advised. For the job I was involved in last year I spent literally tens of hours of work trying to figure out a MOSFET and driver pair that would work and, I just can't spend that amount of time again. I don't mind if you link a data sheet so I can take a quick look of course. I can say that your best bet is to use a GaN MOSFET.

Comment: Andy, i understand, thank you.